# Android Mobile Application

Tags: android

I am in BE IT and my final year project is Text to Speech Mobile Application but I want to add more features so I got an idea of if blind people want to send message then how blind people will be sending to a normal people?

I searched on google and got some useful results....http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-17105225....I want to ask that Can this idea work on Android mobile application?

P.S. I don't know Android Mobile Application and want to know can this idea made on Android??

Comment: Speech to text? Blind person speaks. it writes it down.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good start is to check the TTS engine on Android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

From my point of view, Android is one of the most open mobile platform. So I'm pretty sure your idea is possible to realise on this system !

Good luck for your project.